# add a java class as a bean in MULE

Tags: java, wsdl, mule, payload, mule-flow

In MULE 3.3.0 CE, I wrote a simple java class with constructor and two methods, I copied them at below:

```
 public class Book {
        private String title;

        public Book(String theTitle) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            title = theTitle;
        }

        public String getTitle(){
            return title;
        }

        public String displayAuthorName(String authorName) {
            return authorName;
        }
    }
```

Now I want to add my java class, as a bean in my .mflow(Configuration XML) and then pass payload to the java class method.

How can I do this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get this done, you need to:

1. Define your component as a spring bean.
2. Define the entry point of your component.
3. Use your component within a flow.

Here is an example:

```
package com.mypackage.test;

import org.mule.api.annotations.param.Payload;

    public class MyComponent {

    private String myProperty;

    public String getMyProperty() {
        return myProperty;
    }

    public void setMyProperty(String myProperty) {
        this.myProperty = myProperty;
    }

    public String doProcess(@Payload String payload) {
        //do something interesting
        return "You said: " + payload;
    }

}
```

A way to define the entry point is by using the @Payload annotation.

And then a sample flow:

```
<spring:bean id="myBean" class="com.mypackage.test.MyComponent">
    <spring:property name="myProperty" value="Some Value" />
</spring:bean>

<flow name="componentFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8082/test" />
    <component>
        <spring-object bean="myBean" />
    </component>
    <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/plain" doc:name="Property" />
</flow>
```

Comment: Alberto López Cava, How can I use my java class methods? I want to call them and give an output from my methods by using spring in .mflow(Configuration XML) file